# How to send data from expressjs to react client?

Tags: reactjs, express, stripe-payments

I have a `payments.js` page that use a custom form to make a payemnt with stripe which looks like this

```
async handleSubmit() {
    const { firstName, lastName, email, cardNo, expiryDate, cvv, nameOnCard } = this.state
    const { price } = this.props.location.state.item

    this.setState({
        loading: true
    });

    await axios.post("/charge", {
        firstName,
        lastName,
        email,
        cardNo,
        expiryDate,
        cvv,
        nameOnCard,
        price
    }).then((res) => this.setState({ iframeLink: res.data.next_action.redirect_to_url.url, loading: false }))
        .catch((error) => console.log('ERR', error))

    // I want this to wait for changes
    await axios.post("/api/stripe/webhooks").then((res) => console.log(res)).catch((err) => console.log(err))

}
```

I am opening the url received in first post in `iframe` and once the 3d secure is done I want to get stripe hooks with this line which is called once after first post and then will not update once another hook is received

```
await axios.post("/api/stripe/webhooks").then((res) => console.log(res)).catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

My problem here is that the data is never received in this action

In server the post function looks like this

```
// Stripe Webhooks
app.post("/api/stripe/webhooks", async function (req, res) {
  try {
    const query = req.body;
    res.sendStatus(200);
    console.log(query)
    res.end(JSON.stringify(query))
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("/webhooks route error: ", err);
  }
});
```

Any idea how to catch the data when is received?

Comment: i would recon the /charge route is also in the server and is working correctly?
can you put a console log before the axios call and see if it gets there? (its not clear wether you know the request is sent or not

Comment: @user3809982 thats's correct. As I am receiving the 3d secure url to open

Comment: edited for further questions

Comment: which data do you want to receive? your post action is empty in the client (without any body)

Comment: @user3809982 the request is sent because `console.log(query)` from server is responding and also I receive this in `console.log(res)` from '/api/stripe/webhooks' but only after I receive the response from first post. `data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}` But after finishing the payment it will not update

Comment: Didnt quite get it, can you elaborate, and maybe on the post itself ?

Comment: @user3809982 I have updated my post and description